# TypeError: b.split is not a function error

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get data from MySQL via vue -> axios -> php. In response to the request, cath(error) fires with the following error:

```
TypeError: b.split is not a function
    at index.js:1:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.exports (index.js:1:1)
    at t.exports (index.js:1:1)
    at h.request (index.js:1:1)
    at h.n.forEach.h.<computed> [as get] (index.js:1:1)
    at Function.get (index.js:1:1)
    at Vue.getDrivers (drivers.php:78:23)
    at Vue.mounted (drivers.php:95:18)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.js:1872:59)
```

in this file (drivers.php)

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#newdriver',
        data: {
            drivers: [],
        },

        methods: {
            getDrivers() {
                axios.get({
                    url: 'scripts/drivers-action.php',
                    method: 'get',
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log("result");
                        console.log(res);
                        this.drivers = res.data.rows;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        // handle error
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
        },

        mounted: function() {
            this.getDrivers();
        },
    });
</script>
```

drivers-action.php:

```
<?php
    include('../dbcon.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers";
    $rows = getAllDrivers();

    function getAllDrivers() {
        $data = [];
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        if($statement->execute()) {
            $data = $statment->fetchAll();
        }
        return $data;
    }

    $data = array('rows' => $rows);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I can't figure out what is the problem and what is causing this error.

EDITED:
dbconn.php, where i define $conn object for database connect

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli(
        'localhost',
        'root',
        '',
        'beldum'
    );
    if($conn -> connect_error) {
        die('Error: ('.$conn->connect_errno.')'.$conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You might need to update or downgrade your Axios. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4638

Comment: @aynber i'm alreay download axios in project and in other place it works

Comment: Where are `$conn` and `$sql` set in your function?

Comment: @brombeer i'm updated question with `$conn`. `$sql` defined in `drivers-action.php:4`

Comment: Those are not available _in_ your function though ([Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)). Does `drivers-action.php` return any results when you call it in your browser/address bar?

Comment: @brombeer in this case i get error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null`. But I still can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It's happening because of variable scope, as I mentioned. `$conn` and `$sql` are not available _in_ your function, they're declared outside of it. Either pass them as parameters to your function or, since there seems no real use to it, get rid of the function

Comment: fyi, you also get that error when calling the page via axios. You can/should use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see/debug what data gets returned from Ajax calls